# Responsive page: simplest method to transform a row into two or three

Tags: html, css

I recreate my first Google-homepage and I struggle to allow my footer responsive in two or three rows when the page size change.
Currently when I change the size of the window's browser I've always one row.

Which is the good way do get something responsive:  flexbox, grid, media-queries... ?

I try this:

```css
#footer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "pub entreprise propos comment neutre infos confidentialite conditions parametres";
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#pub{
    grid-area: pub;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add css display flex and change it with flex-direction